# error with cx_freeze No module named 'ttkwidgets'

Tags: python, cx-freeze, ttkwidgets

I want to freeze my program but when I do that and I launch the .exe I have the following message

```
No module named 'ttkwidgets'
```

Here the install file

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': 'atexit'
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('BouclePrincipale.py', base="Win32GUI")
]

setup(name='simple_Tkinter',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze Tkinter script',
      executables=executables
      )
```

Comment: Have you tried using pip to install ttkwidgets?

Comment: I use pip to install because the program work with no probleme before freeze it

Comment: Do you have the tkinter module itself installed?

Comment: I think yes, tkinter isn't include in python by default ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Try "pip install tkinter" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: the function doesn't work. Well I copy the folder ttkwidgets into the lib folder of the build. after I have other error with font and filedialog => well I add from tkinter import font
from tkinter import filedialog after that a problem with PIL and image I do that python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow and it's work

Comment: as an alternative try using pyinstaller?

Comment: @CoolCloud I don't know this software... I will see how it's work

Comment: `pip install pyinstaller` and u can use flags inside your terminal itself to make a exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I dowloaded the folder of ttkwidgets and I manualy put into the folder Lib.
After that I had plenty other error (sorry I didn't write the error) but I had to add in the script

```
from tkinter import font 
from tkinter import filedialog
```

after that I had a problem with PIL and image and I do that

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

And when I freeze my program all it's working